# Combine characters and numbers php

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I am stripping data from a pdf file, so I convert pdf to txt and got data from it. I get main record in string like this
 `CARDS 1 GA350C 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGCL R 90 . 0 55.0 2Y 4 4 #` 
when there is only one record and sometime I get multiple records in single string like this, I figured out with "#" character that there is more than one record in string
 `Invite 1 MA300C 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGCL R 9 9 . 0 210.0 6 Y 4 4 #RSVP 1 OFF-90 A 1 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGBH S 9 9 . 0 210.0 6 N 1 0 #Letter1 1 MA130C 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGC L R 29 7 . 0 210.0 2 N 4 0 #Letter1 1 OFF-90 A 1 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGBH S 29 7 . 0 210.0 2 N 1 0 #Envelopes 1 ENVDL E P F S 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGBH S 13 0 . 0 225.0 1 N 1 0 #` 
In first line actual string should like
 `CARDS 1 GA350C 320.0 450.0 DIGCLR 90.0 55.0 2 Y 4 4`
Here Y stand for Yes so this character is sometime N stand for No 
**How can I join numbers and letters in manner I showed? It has to work regardless of string length** 
 I've used

```
$string = "CARDS 1 GA350C 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGCL R 90 . 0 55.0 2Y 4 4 #";
$newstring = preg_replace("/(\d+)\s+(?=\d+)/", "$1", $string);
```

But no luck, is anybody has solution please? Thanks for viewing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it in one `preg_replace`.

The following code will bring all the oddly-formatted numbers into the new format, for example:

```
    $string = "CARDS 1 GA350C 3 2 0 . 0 450.0 DIGCL R 90 . 0 55.0 2 Y 4 4";
    preg_match_all("/(\d+\s)+\.\s?0/", $string, $matches);
    $newNumbers = array_map(
        function ($number) { return str_replace(' ', '', $number); },
        $matches[0]
    );
    $newstring = str_replace($matches[0], $newNumbers, $string);
```

Result:

> CARDS 1 GA350C 320.0 450.0 DIGCL R 90.0 55.0 2 Y 4 4

Comment: Thanks BVengerov its almost what I needed except one thing. I can find no of records so that's not a problem but in your demo notice that DIGCL R this is one word DIGCLR stands for DigitalColor so can I join R with DIGCL? It doesn't remain same. Sometime it's DIGBHS or DIGBLW. Thanks and appreciate your suggestion.